# Heroku/MongoDB - How to update all the documents using a value from a subcollection?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

What I want to achieve is to update a field for all the documents (million+) in a collection using a value of another field. Since it's not possible to refer to the document itself in an update, I have to use a function and it works...

```
db.Sounds.find({}).snapshot().forEach(
  function(sound) {

    var duration = NumberInt(sound.files[0].metadata.duration);

    db.Sounds.update({
      _id: sound._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        duration: duration
      }
    });
  }
);
```

... but it times out after 10 mins on Heroku because it performs really slow (each updated takes 300-400ms) due to network communication.

Another alternative is to use eval to run JavaScript code server-side but 'heroku' user doesn't seem to have sufficient permissions to run eval.

Is there any way around these limitations?

Comment: did you try to set `MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;` before running your statement ?

Comment: Hi Frédéric, thank you for the reply. I didn't try that because each update takes 300-400ms, so the script would take 4-5 days to complete which is not really an acceptable solution.